# How to download source code of any "xyz" package with all dependencies in form of source code / deb file?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS machine . I have another 25 Ubuntu machines to install same software packages .
So , suppose I want to install gimp in 25 systems . If I will apt-get install gimp , it will utilize lots of bandwidth . Alternatively to me , downloading source code with all the dependencies and compiling them once forming a deb file .

Hence installing from deb file will make process very easy . 
So how to achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

Consider configuring apt-proxy or usual web proxy. Then deb packages will only be downloaded once. Alternatively you can download all gimp dependencies (with `apt-get install --download-only gimp`) and install then on all your hosts using `dpkg -i`.
Source code is not needed here as DEB files (which are already compiled and do not contain source code) are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Its fairly simple. Apt-get stores deb files in /var/cache/apt/archives. I'd recommend starting with a system without these installed and running `apt-get clean` to clear out the cache, then copying the files over. You can then install them with dpkg, assuming its a one shot thing.

If you need to do this often, there used to be a software for offline updates called keryx. Ubuntu also seems to [recommend](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Use_apt-offline) something called apt-offline or you can use [aptoncd](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/create-backup-of-all-installed-packages-using-aptoncd-in-ubuntu.html) - the first bundles up and installs packages as a zip file, the latter creates a little repository on a cd.